# Complex power function

Tags: complex-analysis

I would like to know if there exists a curve on the complex plane through which the function f(z)= z^i is constant,it can be any curve- circular,linear or whatever comes across your mind. I haven't managed to find one, if anyone can give me a little guidance on that or a hint whether this claim is true or not , it would be very much appreciated.

Comment: What does $z^i$ mean?

Comment: regardless of its interpretation (eg what branch of the logarithm one takes), looking at the absolute value, we need $\arg z$ to be constant so $z$ is on a ray through the origin, but then $e^{i\log |z|}$ cannot be constant unless $z$ is in a discrete set, so the answer is no